# Trigger en sql no funciona

Tags: php, sql

Tengo el siguiente trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_updStockPedido` AFTER INSERT ON `detalle_pedido` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE modelos_ventas SET stock = stock - NEW.cantidad
WHERE modelos_ventas.sku = NEW.sku;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Resulta que, cuando levanto un pedido, en ocasiones hace el descuento, en ocasiones en vez de restar lo suma, y en ocasiones no hace nada. ¿Cómo podría resolver esto?

Comment: todo depende del where en este caso, tienes que fijarte que la columna SKU sea NOT NULL y , por tanto, siempre obtenga algún valor en los INSERT. De lo contrario alterará el resultado o no hará nada, como bien señalas.

Comment: Convendría ver además que restricciones tiene tu columna `cantidad`, pues no validas nada con respecto a ella. ¿Y si es un valor negativo o nulo? Debes poner restricciones en algunos casos para no llevarte sorpresas de mal gusto.

Comment: Cuando lo suma, qué valor trae ese campo cantidad? Has visto algún error en los logs de PHP? cómo es un registro "típico" de `detalle_pedido`? Cómo es la consulta que realizas desde PHP cuando _levantas un pedido_? Por favor, ve a [edit] y añade esa información EN la pregunta. :)